# gridview cell back color on condition based not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with the following columns

[image]

Columns 5 is Date.

Columns 6 is Failure.

If failures is 0 or null, cell  color will be green.
If failures is not 0 or not null, cell color will be red. So far these conditions I have done.

My question is in the last three columns if date is not null, then cell color should be red. How to achieve that?

my code is as follows

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[6];
        string Failures = cell.Text.ToString().Trim();
        string date = e.Row.Cells[5].ToString();
        if (Failures == "0" || Failures == "NULL")
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Handel the even  `GridView1_RowDataBound` event for your GridView.

```
     protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
            //Check if it is not header or footer row
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
              string Failures =DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "YourColumnN°6Name").ToString().Trim();
                string date = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "YourColumnN°5_Name").ToString().ToString();
                //Check your condition here 
               if (Failures == "0" || Failures == "NULL")
                     e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Green;
                else
                     e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red;              
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, to change my gridview cell background color 
`GridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.Add("background-color", "white");`
I hope that will helps you
Edit:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        { //if(GridView.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text!=null) //for date
            if(GridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text == "0" || GridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text == "NULL")
            {
                 GridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
            }
            else
                GridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Style.Add("background-color", "red");
            }
        }
```

Comment: But how to know that particular row?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
protected void GridViewName_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[6];
        string Failures = cell.Text.ToString().Trim();
        string date = e.Row.Cells[5].ToString();
        if (Failures == "0" || Failures == "NULL")
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out dt))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[5].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `RowDataBound` event you should determine flags based on the row data source and not a reinterpretation of the cell contents.

I would also suggest that a Database NULL value should not be overlaid with a status of "Good" or "Bad".  If a null represents a "Good" status then your `SELECT` statement should reflect that state.  It should not be left to the WebApp to determine data states as this could lead to different interpretations of the same data across different pages.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem;

        Boolean StatusOK = ( drv["Failure"] == DBNull.Value || (int) drv["Failure"] == 0 );
        Boolean HaveDate = ( drv["Date"] != DBNull.Value );

        e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = (StatusOK && HaveDate ? Color.Green : Color.Red);
    }
}
```